# Dynamically add custom instance methods to a mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, database-schema

Is there a way to add [custom instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) to a mongoose schema after it has already been "exported".

For example, if I have a schema:

```
module.exports = function(app, db, config) {

  var MySchema = new Schema({ name: String });
  MySchema.methods.doIt = function() { console.log("I DID IT!"); }
  db.model("MySchema", MySchema);
}
```

Then I want to add new methods to the schema dynamically after it has already been loaded into the mongoose model object.

```
MySchema = db.model('MySchema');
var obj = new MySchema({name: "robocop"});

var myNewMethod = function() { console.log(this.name); }

// Do Magic here to add the myNewMethod to object.

obj.myNewMethod();
```

---

**Did You Even Try?**

I have already tried to just add it to the mongoose model object, however this produces errors saying the schema objects do not have the method I just added.

```
MySchema = db.model('MySchema');
MySchema.schema.methods.myNewMethod = function() { console.log(this.name); }
db.model('MySchema', MySchema);

console.log(MySchema.schema.methods); // This shows my method was added!

...

var obj = new MySchema({name: "robocop"});
obj.myNewMethod(); //ERROR:  YOUR METHOD DOESN'T EXIST!
```

Answer (score 0):

Caveat coder.  It is possible, and whether or not it's a good idea is left as an exercise for the reader.

Your schema is of course affected by the schema object, not any particular instance of your model.  Thus, if you want to modify the schema, you'll need to have access to the schema itself.

Here's an example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db       = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/sandbox_development")

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  blurb: String
})

var model = mongoose.model('thing', schema)

var instance = new model({blurb: 'this is an instance!'})

instance.save(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log("problem saving instance")

  schema.add({other:  String})  // teh secretz

  var otherInstance = new model({blurb: 'and I am dynamic', other: 'i am new!'})
  otherInstance.save(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log("problem saving other instance", err)

    process.exit(0)
  })
})
```

Notice the call to `schema.add` which [`Schema` calls internally when you make a new one](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/schema.js#L73).

Comment: I have seen the [schema.add](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add) method, however I was under the impression that this only adds properties to the schema object and does NOT add methods to the schema object.